# _GET php returns empty parameters

Tags: php, parameters, get

I have a php _GET problem. When I received a URL with parameters, they are not "seen" by _GET

```
    echo '<BR>HERE ARE THE GETs :';
    
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    {
      echo '<BR>------ ' . $key . " : " . $value . "<br />";
    }
```

this returns empty strings, when my URL have parameters. This used to work until I migrated to a new wordpress host.

Any clue ? I'm really stuck !

```
    echo '<BR>HERE ARE THE GETs :';
    
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    {
      echo '<BR>------ ' . $key . " : " . $value . "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Might be a security feature blocking it. Try echoing a single one like `$_GET['q']` and see if it works.

Comment: it displays an empty string, although I passed the q=AAA in the url